# How to enable hot reload on some simple JS functions (not React / Vue)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, hot-reload

I have a classic demo project using Vue/cli for the frontend.

Runnin `npm run serve` works well, any changes to the components are indeed hot reloaded.

Now, what if I also want the code from `mylib.js` to be reloaded when changed.

Let's say `mylib.js` is the following code.

```
const XXX = window.XXX || { 
  foo: () => { alert("BAR TEST 1")},
}

window.XXX = XXX;
```

I call `XXX.foo()` it shows `BAR TEST 1`, then if I edit `BAR TEST 1` to `BAR TEST 2` I see that the change is picked up by `npm run serve` but `XXX.foo()` is not reloaded.

Digging a bit in webpack I saw some mentions about some `hot()` API. Do I need to write `mylib.js` differently? (modules).

**vue.config.js**

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
    publicPath: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
    outputDir: './dist/',
    pages: {
      main: {
        entry: 'src/main.js',
      },
      mylib: {
        entry: 'src/mylib.js',
      }
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {

        config.optimization
            .splitChunks(false)

        config
            .plugin('BundleTracker')
            .use(BundleTracker, [{filename: '../frontend/webpack-stats.json'}])

        config.resolve.alias
            .set('__STATIC__', 'static')

        config.devServer
            .public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')
            .host('0.0.0.0')
            .port(8080)
            .hotOnly(true)
            .watchOptions({poll: 1000})
            .https(false)
            .headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["\*"]})
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as having:

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    // call your js update code here
}
```